# Get Number of Rows from a Select Statement Efficiently

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Until recently I've been using `mysql_real_escape_string()` to fix most of my variables before making SQL queries to my database.  A friend said that I should be using PDO's prepared statements instead, so after reading a bit about them I'm now switching over to them.

I've only encountered one problem so far in switching over, and that's counting the rows to returned by a `SELECT` statement.  On occasion in my code, I'd run an SQL query and then count the number of rows returned from the `SELECT` statement.  Depending on whether a result set returned, I would take different actions.  Sometimes I do need to use the result set from it.  MySQL let me go straight to `mysql_fetch_assoc()` after `mysql_num_rows()` with no problem.  However, PDO doesn't seem to have anything like `mysql_num_rows()`.

I've been reading some responses on SO that gave me a solution, to either use `COUNT()` in the SQL statement or to use the PHP function `count()` on the result set.  `COUNT()` would work fine in the SQL statement if I didn't need the result set in some places, however, several people have mentioned that using `count()` on the result set is fairly inefficient.

So my question is, how should I be doing this if I need to count the number of rows selected (if any), then run a script with the result set?  Is using `count()` on the result set the only way in this case, or is there a more efficient way to do things?

Below is a short example of something similar to my previous SQL code:

```
$query=mysql_query('SELECT ID FROM Table WHERE Name='Paul' LIMIT 1);

if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0)
{
  print_r(mysql_fetch_assoc($query));
}
else
{
  //Other code.
}
```

Thanks.

*EDIT*

I do know that you use `fetchAll()` on the statement before counting the result set (which gives me what I need), but I'm just trying to figure out the most efficient way to do things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$stmt->rowCount();
```

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

the rows must be fetched(buffered into memory, or iterated) for it to work. It's not uncommon for your pdo driver to be configured to do this automatically.

Comment: The manual states it doesn't work for all databases.  I suppose it wouldn't hurt to try it, I just accepted that my database probably wouldn't work with it.  Will give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use Count(). You can run two queries like

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Table WHERE Name='Paul'
```

one you have get the count, then run the query with select clause

```
SELECT ID FROM Table WHERE Name='Paul' LIMIT 1
```

`Count()` function is not inefficient at all if you are using it like `COUNT(ID)`, because most probably `id` is primary key and have an index. MYSQL wont even have to access the table.

Comment: So it would be more efficient to run two queries, as opposed to a single query and then count the result set?  *EDIT* I was saying that the PHP function `count()` was inefficient, not the SQL function `COUNT()`.

Comment: In this instance, in both cases you are limiting the result to 1 element. So it very well might be, at least in some ways.